# Examples when algebraic 1-stack = derived enhancement?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, stacks, derived-algebraic-geometry

Are there any examples where a usual algebraic 1-stack $X$ and the corresponding derived stack enhancement $\mathbb{R}X$ coincide?

Let me take an example from notes of Bertrand Toen, page 41 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604504.pdf.

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve and consider the functor $i: \mathrm{St}(k) \to \mathrm{dSt}(k)$. Take $X$ to be the mapping stack
$$
X = \mathrm{Map}(C,BG) = \mathrm{Bun}_G(C).
$$
The derived enhancement is
$$
\mathbb{R}X = \mathbb{R}\operatorname{Map}(i(C), i(BG)),
$$
and $X$ is called a *truncation* of $\mathbb{R}X$. I am therefore requesting examples where this truncation procedure is trivial!

My naive hope is that this is the case since $\dim(C) = 1$ and so there are no higher cohomologies/homotopies above degree 1.

Comment: Since C is a curve, $\mathbb{R}X$ is actually smooth, in particular $\mathbb{R}X \simeq X$ in this case. Similar examples would be the derived moduli stacks of coherent sheaves or vector bundles on a curve, or derived moduli of representations of a quiver: these are all smooth and hence coincide with their truncations. Derived phenomena starts appearing when you go one dimension up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That is exactly what I need. Do you have a reference for smooth implies derived = underived?

Comment: Also, what happens in the case $X = \mathrm{Higgs}_G(C) = T^{*}\mathrm{Bun}_G(C)$, do we still get $\mathbb{R} X \cong X$? Perhaps for only certain G, like G semisimple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $S$ is a smooth projective variety of dimension $d$, then the derived stack $X=Bun_G(S)$ has cotangent complex perfect of amplitude $[-(d-1), 1]$. If $S=C$ is a curve then it is in $[0,1]$, in particular $H^*(\mathbb{L}_X)=0$ for $*<0$. For stacks, this condition (+ finite presentation) is exactly smoothness.

Smooth morphisms $X \to Y$ are flat, which in the derived context means flatness on classical truncations but also $\pi_i(O_Y) \otimes_{\pi_0(O_Y)} \pi_0(O_X) \simeq \pi_i(O_X)$ on higher homotopy.  In particular, saying that a derived stack is smooth over the base field $k$ automatically implies that its derived structure is trivial. I would refer you to the original references on DAG, such as [HAG II, 2.2.2].

For $X = Higgs_G(S)$ we typically have one extra obstruction $H^{-d}(\mathbb{L}_X) \ne 0$ compared to $Bun_G(S)$. For $S=C$ a curve this means that $X$ is only quasi-smooth in general. The extra obstruction $H^{-1}$ does vanish in certain special cases, e.g. if $G$ is semisimple, see Beilinson-Drinfeld "Quantization of Hitchin..." 2.1.2 and also Halpern-Leistner's paper on Verlinde for Higgs, Prop 3.14.